# drag rows in Excel worksheet to show all

Tags: microsoft-excel

I selected row 54 to bring the totals up to row 14 and now I can't bring them back down to expose all the rows I covered over.

Comment: Please clarify: Totals of what? What do you mean by "bring them back down"? Your question does not communicate the context necessary to allow us to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you've hidden the rows, you can select the rows either side (shift+click on their row-numbers) and then choose unhide from the context menu (right-click).